# SSIS "Insert bulk failed due to a schema change of the target table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am developing a SSIS package in bids and getting an inconsistent error SSIS   "Insert bulk failed due to a schema change of the target table  nOT CONSISTENT for one of my dataflows. It is successful sometimes but also fails sometimes giving the above mentioned error.

I am not sure what is happening.

Following is storedproc which is called from oledb source

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPartiesIpoData_SSIS]

AS
BEGIN


    SELECT     
        c.companyId 'companyId', 
        tpf.transactionPrimaryFeatureName 'transactionPrimaryFeatureName', 
        os.statusdatetime 'statusdatetime', 
        st.statusName 'statusName'

    FROM ciqCompany c
        inner JOIN ciqTransOffering t 
            ON t.companyId = c.companyId
        JOIN ciqTransOfferToPrimaryFeat ttp 
            ON ttp.transactionId = t.transactionId
        JOIN ciqTransPrimaryFeatureType tpf 
            ON tpf.transactionPrimaryFeatureId = ttp.transactionPrimaryFeatureId
        JOIN ciqtransofferingstatustodate os 
            ON os.transactionId = t.transactionId
        JOIN ciqtransactionstatusType st 
            ON st.statusId = os.statusId AND st.statusId = 2

    WHERE tpf.transactionPrimaryFeatureId = 5 

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PartiesIpoData_companyId on CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.PartiesIpoData(companyId) with (DROP_EXISTING =on)
END
```

The  destination schema  is as follows

[image]

The oledb destination set in SSIS is as follows

[image]

Comment: Is there any maitenance job that is running at the same time with your package?

Comment: Not sure about that . I am running this package via the SQL job. It works fine in QA but repeadetly fails in QA. However when I run in debug mode on dev it succeeds sometimes without the job. That is when I run via the IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is some of the action plan you can try, this helped in my case though.

1) Drop the Constraints before the its run and recreate them after the run

2) Disable the Auto update stats (To isolate the issue)

3) Check if any parallel index rebuilds happening.

4) check with without using "fast load"  option

If still the issue persists after implementing the above change, collect the Profiler trace to capture the activity when it is failing to further investigation.

[Check This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186247(SQL.90).aspx)

also check setting for [SQL Server Destination Adapter](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1867/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-performance-best-practices/)

If still the issue persists after implementing the above change, collect the Profiler trace to capture the activity when bcp is failing to further investigation.